# SharePoint API get items in Document Library does not return .xlsx or .docx items

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of documents in our document library using the API. I do a GET call to [https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/RapidMachiningSolutionsLLC/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('myDocLibrary')/items](https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/RapidMachiningSolutionsLLC/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle(%27myDocLibrary%27)/items), but the data that I receive is only for the .doc files in the library.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to retrieve files from the Document library.

Using the REST API you have used, we need to add select and expand in the query as below.

```
/sites/RapidMachiningSolutionsLLC/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('myDocLibrary')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,*,File/Name&$expand=File
```

Another approach is to use [GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest) method to get all the files.

```
/sites/RapidMachiningSolutionsLLC/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/myDocLibrary')/Files
```

**Make sure you are using the INTERNAL NAME of your document library.**

Comment: The first query you showed still does not include .docx or .xlsx files. I haven't been able to get GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl to work.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can expand files and folders by following rest api

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderUrl')?$expand=Folders,Files
```